# how to embed Schemdraw inside PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

Schemdraw is using matplotlib to draw and show the schematic by python.
for example if you run the following code, it draws in matplot.

Now the question is how to embed this matplotlib inside PyQt5?

thanks

```
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm

d = schemdraw.Drawing(fontsize=10)
d.add(elm.Capacitor())
r=d.add(elm.Resistor(theta=40))
d.add(elm.Diode(label="D1"))
d.draw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the version provided by pypi, you cannot embed schemdraw (at least in a simple way) but reviewing the repository I see that in the next release the draw method is modified to accept an axis so you must install schemdraw from the repository:

```
python -m pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/cdelker/schemdraw.git
```

Then modifying the official matplotlib example you can embed schemdraw:

```py
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets

if QtCore.qVersion() >= "5.":
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
        FigureCanvas,
        NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar,
    )
else:
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
        FigureCanvas,
        NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar,
    )
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)

        canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        layout.addWidget(canvas)
        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(canvas, self))
        ax = canvas.figure.subplots()

        d = schemdraw.Drawing(fontsize=10)
        d.add(elm.Capacitor())
        r = d.add(elm.Resistor(theta=40))
        d.add(elm.Diode(label="D1"))
        d.draw(ax=ax)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Check whether there is already a running QApplication (e.g., if running
    # from an IDE).
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not qapp:
        qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    app.activateWindow()
    app.raise_()
    qapp.exec_()
```

[image]